# How to update the Angular 4 (click) method?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to update the method triggered in the (click) event of a mat-icon component.

```
<mat-icon (click)="setFavorite( $event, 0, coin.ID )">mode_star_border</mat-icon>
```

To be more specific, after clicking the icon I want to update

```
setFavorite( $event, coin.ID )
```

to

```
unsetFavorite( $event, 1 )
```

I have searched but couldn't find how this can be accomplished. To change the icon, I am just changing the innerHTML as follows:

```
event.path[0].innerHTML = 'mode_star';
```

But I couldn't find a similar way for the (click) event.

**Solution:**

```
changeClickFunction() {
    if( this.favoriteID ) {
        this.functionAddress = this.unsetFavorite;    
    } else {
        this.functionAddress = this.setFavorite;
    }
}
```

The setFavorite method returns a favoriteID and sets it before calling the changeClickFunction method, while the unsetFavorite method resets the favoriteID before calling the changeClickFunction method.

**Update:**

The solution outlined above appears incorrect. This only updates the global variables functionAddress and favoriteID, but does not bind these values specifically to the event.target. I need the functionAddress and favoriteID only to be updated for the specific Coin in the table, where the click event was fired.

Comment: Could you change the logic inside of `setFavorite()` instead?

Comment: Why not call a method that handles both cases, e.g. `toggleFavorite`, and let that deal with the state (or dispatch to other functions, if that's what you want) appropriately?

Comment: Toggle could be an option. I thought about it, but I also need it to be specific for one row in a table. So each event is unique and should either set or unset a favorite. It makes an API call to add or delete a row in a database.

Comment: $event is passing all of the "Click" events data, the values of 0 and coin.ID are passed through from the component this view is on. You will need to modify your function on this component class to take less variables and modify your mat-icon click function to match. I do agree with @user3004118 a toggle function could be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a reference to the function it self and bind the click listener to it
something like that

**component.ts**

```
export default class MyComponent {

    functionAddress;
    secondParam;

    ngOnInit() {
        functionAddress = this.setFavorite;
    }

    setFavorite(e , id) {

    }

    unsetFavorite(e , id) {

    }

    changeClickFunction() {
        this.functionAddress = this.unsetFavorite;
        this.secondParam = 1;
    }
}
```

**component.html**

```
/// update second param and set it with coin id if the function address is setFavorite otherwise make it equal 1
<mat-icon (click)="functionAddress($event, secondParam)">mode_star_border</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works like a charm and it is really easy to implement. I will update my question with the solution.

Comment: @user3004118 You don't have to add the answer to your question. Instead, use the tick button under the downvote icon (aka an arrow facing downwards) to accept this answer.